# How to delete gmail contacts from Android phone?

Tags: android, gmail

How do I delete gmail contacts that were automatically added, from my Android phone? Deleting one by one is tedious. Thanks.

Comment: not exactly related to programming...

Comment: Are you trying to develop an application that does this, or are you just asking how to do this for your own phone?

Comment: I'm unsure if this is a question on how to make your own program delete all of those, or how to do a manual cleanup yourself. As such I'm just going to close it as off-topic, not migrate it.

Answer (score 1):

This question probably belongs on [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/). Stack Overflow is is generally only for programing related questions. If you are trying to achieve this programatically check out the [Contacts API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.html) or the newer [ContactsContract API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) I have never used them but I imagine they provide a way to add / remove contacts.